# Storing calculated values in an object

Tags: python, oop, memoization

Recently I've been writing a bunch of code like this:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
    self._y = None

  def y(self):
    if self._y is None:
      self._y = big_scary_function(self.x)

    return self._y

  def z(self, i):
    return nice_easy_function(self.y(), i)
```

In a given class I may have a number of things working like this `y`, and I may have other things that use the stored pre-calculated values.  Is this the best way to do things or would you recommend something different?

Note that I don't pre-calculate here because you might use an instance of `A` without making use of `y`.

I've written the sample code in Python, but I'd be interested in answers specific to other languages if relevant.  Conversely I'd like to hear from Pythonistas about whether they feel this code is Pythonic or not.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this as long as you are okay with lazily evaluating variables. If you are rendering graphics or something similar, you might want to compute things ahead of time.

Comment: There is an alternative approach using the `__getattr__`. It is briefly shown here: http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/slides/2013-08-pyconca/#id65

Comment: `__getattr__` is best avoided now we have descriptors...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, i do not see how to use descriptors instead of `__getattr__` to define "lazily computed" attributes in a class that uses `__slots__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: this is a very common pattern in Python (there's  even a `cached_property` descriptor class somewhere - in Django IIRC).

This being said there are at least two potential issues here.

The first one is common to all 'cached properties' implementations and is the fact that one usually doesn't expect an attribute access to trigger some heavy computation. Whether it's really an issue depends on the context (and near-religious opinions of the reader...)

The second issue - more specific to your example - is the traditional cache invalidation / state consistency problem: Here you have `y` as a function of `x` - or at least that's what one would expect - but rebinding `x` will not update `y` accordingly. This can be easily solved in this case by making `x` a property too and invalidating `_y` on the setter, but then you have even more unexpected heavy computation happening.

In this case (and depending on the context and computation cost)  I'd probably keep memoization  (with invalidation) but provide a more explicit getter to make clear we might have some computation going on.

Edit: I misread your code and imagined a property decorator on `y` - which shows how common this pattern is ;). But my remarks still make sense specially when a "self proclaimed pythonista" posts an answer in favour of a computed attribute.

Edit: if you want a more or less generic "cached property with cache invalidation", here's a possible implementation (might need more testing etc):

```
class cached_property(object):
    """
    Descriptor that converts a method with a single self argument 
    into a property cached on the instance.

    It also has a hook to allow for another property setter to
    invalidated the cache, cf the `Square` class below for
    an example.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.__doc__ = getattr(func, '__doc__')
        self.name = self.encode_name(func.__name__)

    def __get__(self, instance, type=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        if self.name not in instance.__dict__:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise AttributeError("attribute is read-only")

    @classmethod
    def encode_name(cls, name):
        return "_p_cached_{}".format(name)

    @classmethod
    def clear_cached(cls, instance, *names):
        for name in names:
            cached = cls.encode_name(name)
            if cached in instance.__dict__:
                del instance.__dict__[cached]

    @classmethod
    def invalidate(cls, *names):
        def _invalidate(setter):
            def _setter(instance, value):
                cls.clear_cached(instance, *names)
                return setter(instance, value)
            _setter.__name__ = setter.__name__
            _setter.__doc__ =  getattr(setter, '__doc__')
            return _setter
        return _invalidate



class Square(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size

    @cached_property
    def area(self):
        return self.size * self.size

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size

    @size.setter
    @cached_property.invalidate("area")
    def size(self, size):
        self._size = size
```

Not that I think the added cognitive overhead is worth the price actually - most often than not a plain inline implementation makes the code easier to understand and maintain (and doesn't require much more LOCs) - but it still might be useful if a package requires a lot of cached properties and  cache invalidation.

Comment: Thanks.  In my use case `x` will never change once the instance is initialized, so I won't have to worry about invalidation.  In light of that is there anything else I ought to do?

Comment: If `x` isn't supposed to change after initialisation you may want to make it a read-only property, and if you choose to stick to an explicit getter for `y` then naming it something like `get_y()` might avoid some confusion (just naming it `y()` kind of make it looks like a property,  so someone might forget to actually call the method and be a bit surprised to get an unbound method as value).

Answer (score 2):

As a self-proclaimed Pythonista, I would prefer using the `property` decorator in this situation:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_y'):
            self._y = big_scary_function(self.x)
        return self._y

    def z(self, i):
        return nice_easy_function(self.y, i)
```

Here `self._y` is also lazy evaluated. The `property` allows you to refer to `self.x` and `self.y` on the same footing. That is, when working with an instance of the class, you treat both `x` and `y` as attributes, even though `y` is written as a method.

I've also used `not hasattr(self, '_y')` instead of `self._y is None`, which allows me to skip the `self.y = None` declaration in `__init__`. You can of course use your method here and still go with the `property` decorator.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this will also help with my IDE inferring the wrong type for _y.

Comment: Common idiom yes but it can have some drawbacks too - cf my answer. Nb not wanting to start a holy war here, as I mention I do use this pattern too but you have to consider the context and weight the pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

My [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp) pythonista approach is described by the following snippet.

My classes inherit `_reset_attributes` from `WithAttributes` and use it to invalidate the scary values.

```
class WithAttributes:

    def _reset_attributes(self, attributes):
        assert isinstance(attributes,list)
        for attribute in attributes:
            try:
                delattr(self, '_' + attribute)
            except:
                pass

class Square(WithAttributes):

    def __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size

    @property
    def area(self):
        try:
            return self._area
        except AttributeError:
            self._area = self.size * self.size
            return self._area

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size

    @size.setter
    def size(self, size):
        self._size = size
        self._reset_attributes('area')
```

Comment: You don't need a base class and inheritance here,  a plain function would work just the same. And a bare except clause that just pass,  OMG ! If the point is to provide a generic "cached property with invalidation" there are much better ways.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You keep commenting but don't give an example. We would all be happy to learn from you, if you only showed it to us. This is obviously a small snippet and doesn't show everything. I left what I thought would help.

Comment: Sorry I'm posting from my phone so typing a full blown code snippet would be quite a PITA.

Comment: StackOverflow is a good tool to help people that need help. I don't see how you showing up here and criticizing other people's answer helps. If you can't help with the phone, then don't help and leave us alone. I noticed that most of your activity is criticizing, not helping with code examples.

Comment: cf my edited answer. Please criticize it at will, I won't be upset.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers On this page you have 6 comments and 1 answer with 7 editings. The final result of the answer is good, but all this noise makes this page messy. When I add a comment or an answer I always think how clear it is and if someone will learn from it. I hope that this very comment will teach you to keep adding good quality content to your future answers and avoid as much noise as you added to this one.