# Recreate class object changing one constructor argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I'd like to have implement an `update` method in my class that recreates the class but changes just one constructor argument.

My attempt:

```
class Updateable:
    def update(self, var, var_str, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(self._vars)
        kwargs[var_str] = var
        self.__init__(**kwargs)

class Rectangle(Updateable):
    def __init__(self, length, perimeter):
        self._vars = locals()
        self.length = length
        self.width = 0.5*(perimeter - 2.*length)      

r = Rectangle(10, 20)
r.update('perimeter', 16)
```

The problem is, the whole `locals()` thing, I think, is pretty dodgy, and it means that any class that is `Updateable` needs to assign `self._vars`.

What would be the correct way to achieve this functionality?  Decorators, metaclasses?  Something simpler?

Comment: Calling `__init__` after the object already exists seems a bit strange.  Why not just have a `recalculate_width` method or something?

Comment: Because I want it to work for other classes I have, which all have different argument names.  Sometimes it's `width`, sometimes it's `angle`, sometimes it's `wavelength`, could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question, or if you don't want high level advise and your just question solved.

What your `__init__` currently does is recalculate the properties of a geometric shape if a (possibly relevant) variable is changed. Step 1 is to take this out of the `__init__`, and into a seperate `def` which is called by init. The main thing here is that you do not pass variables to this function, but use the class variables which have been set in either `__init__` or one the superclass updating methods.

Step 2 is to change your update function.
Python has a form of getters and setters called [properties](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) allowing you to hook tasks to updating your variables. On the other hand a more generalized way is more similar to your own update, and is listed as option 2 below

## Example alternative

```
class Updateable:
    # Option 1
    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return self.__perimeter

    @perimeter.setter
    def perimeter(self, perimeter):
        self.__perimeter = perimeter
        self.recalculate_everything() # or self.calculate_width() or something

    # Option 2
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        self.recalculate_everything

class Rectable(Updateable):
    def __init__(self, length, perimeter):
        self.__length = length
        self.__perimeter = perimeter
        recalculate_everything()

    def recalculate_everything():
        self.calculate_width()
        ...     

    def calculate_width():
        self.__width = 0.5*(self.__perimeter - 2.*self.__length)
```

Comment: 1/ Don't use double underscores for implementation attributes - this triggers a name mangling function that will break inheritance. Only use a single leading underscore. 2/ if you use inheritance, then call the superclass initializer. 3/ In Python 2.x, properties won't properly work with old-style classes. 4/ Your "Updatable" class should either define "recalculate_everything()" with a default implementation or be an abstract base class (cf the stlib's ABC module). 5/ you have a NameError in `Rectangle.__init__` (...)

Comment: And 6. manually setting the implementation attributes in the initializer instead of using the propery setters kind of defeat the whole point of having a property.

Comment: Oh and yes too: the point of `Updatable` was to be generic - it should know nothing about specific implementation attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive criticism

Answer (score 2):

Laurens Koppenol suggested using `properties` (Python's generic support for computed attribute) which is a good idea but his example code is both broken in many ways and more complicated than it has to be, so here's a simpler, working and pythonic example (no `Updatable` class nor any other extraneous stuff required):

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, length, perimeter):
        self.length = length
        self.perimeter = perimeter

    @property
    def width(self):
        return 0.5*(self.perimeter - 2.*self.length)
```

If you want to cache the `width` value (to avoid useless computations) but still make sure it's updated when `length` or `perimeter` change, you'll need to make them all properties:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, length, perimeter):
        self.length = length
        self.perimeter = perimeter

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        self._length = value
        self._width = None


    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return self._perimeter

    @length.setter
    def perimiter(self, value):
        self._perimeter = value
        self._width = None

    @property
    def width(self):
        if self._width is None:
            self._width = 0.5*(self.perimeter - 2.*self.length)     
        return self._width
```

or (if you have a lot of such stuff) use some "cached_property with invalidation" implementation as this one: [Storing calculated values in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228551/storing-calculated-values-in-an-object/41230310#41230310)

edit: wrt/ your question, the call to `locals` is indeed ugly (and can easily break - you may have local variables that are not supposed to be parts of `_vars`), as well as the need to explicitely set `self._vars` in child classes. Also the `update()` API is itself quite ugly IMHO. Now you don't need anything fancy to make the whole thing more pythonic - here's a solution whose only boilerplate is the need to call `Updateable.__init__` with named arguments (won't work with positional ones):

```
class Updateable(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._vars = kwargs

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        vars = self._vars.copy()
        vars.update(**kwargs)
        self.__init__(**vars)


class Rectangle(Updateable):
    def __init__(self, length, perimeter):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__(length=length, perimeter=perimeter)
        self.length = length
        self.width = 0.5*(perimeter - 2.*length)

r = Rectangle(10, 20)
r.update(perimeter=40)
```

As a side note, I personnaly find quite disturbing that your `Rectangle` class takes a `perimeter` argument but stores a `width` instead... Maybe you should consider a `perimeter` property ? (even if read-only to avoid recomputing etc)

Comment: In your second example, did you mean to assign to `self._length/_perimeter` in the initialisation method?

Comment: So the thing is, I want to apply the updating to many classes, all which have different parameters, and I wanted to avoid having to write every single parameter as a `propery`.  This is why I tried to make a generic class that could do this.  Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @snakecharmerb  no, I meant what I wrote : assigning to `self.length` and `self.perimeter`.  Why would I bypass my properties setters and break the `width` getter code ?

Comment: @Jean-Luc yes sorry - cf my edited answer that do address your question. But I can't garantee it will never break anything....

Answer (score 1):

As others have observed, computations like `width` should be moved to a property or method; they don't belong in an initialiser.

If you really want to return a new instance, this would work for the simplest cases, where the instance's attributes are immutable objects like strings or integers:

```
import copy

class Copyable:

    """Mixin to create copies with a changed attribute."""

    def copy_and_modify(self, var, var_str, **kwargs):
        new = copy.copy(self)
        setattr(new, var, var_str)
        return new

class Rectangle(Copyable):

    def __init__(self, length, perimeter):
        self.perimeter = perimeter
        self.length = length

    @property
    def width(self):
        return 0.5 * (self.perimeter - 2.0 * self.length)
```

however if your objects contain nested mutable structures such as dictionaries or lists you would need to change `copy_and_modify` to use `copy.deepcopy` (but note deep copying is slow)

```
class Copyable:

    def copy_and_modify(self, var, var_str, **kwargs):
        new = copy.deepcopy(self)
        setattr(new, var, var_str)
        return new
```

You can define `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods in your subclasses [as described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to fine-tune control over the copying process.

Comment: If it creates a new instance, the method should not be named `update()`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  I was adhering to the OP's original convention, but you are correct.  The OP was re-initialising the existing instance rather creating a new one.  I'll fix the name later today.  `create_modified_copy` perhaps?  Also, I will rename the mixin to something that corresponds to more closely to it's purpose.