# How to memoize a property in Python?

Tags: python, properties, memoization

Consider the following minimal example:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.a = 1

    @property
    def sum(self):
        print 'Recalculating sum'
        return self.a + self.b

foo = Foo()
print foo.sum
print foo.sum   # Prints 'Recalculating sum' even though neither a or b has changed since previous call
foo.a = 2
print foo.sum   # a has been changed to 2 so recalculation is necessary
```

I would like to memoize `sum` such that if `self.a` and `self.b` doesn't change, then we don't need to keep recalculating the property.

The property should only be recalculated when either `self.a` or `self.b` has changed -- is there an simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use properties for `a` and `b` too and clear up your cache in the setters:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        self._clearsum()

     @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
        self._clearsum()

    def _clearsum(self):
        self._sum = None

    @property
    def sum(self):
        if self._sum is None:
            self._sum = self.a + self.b
        return self._sum
```

Or if you want something a bit more generic, you can check this too:
[Storing calculated values in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228551/storing-calculated-values-in-an-object/41230310#41230310)

Edit : someone recently suggested adding `self._sum = None` in `__init__` to "avoid an error when accessing sum", but that's actually not necessary - `__init__` invokes `a.setter`, which invokes `_clearsum`, which sets the `_sum` attribute, so it's garanteed `self._sum` will be created whatever.

Comment: This is the one that actually does what the question asks for.

Answer (score 13):

python3:

```
from functools import lru_cache as memoized

@property
@memoized(maxsize=1)
def sum(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

python 3.8

```
from functools import cached_property

@cached_property
def sum(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

Comment: There's also `@cached_property` (from 3.8 on). I'm not sure how it differs from stacking `@property` on top of `@cache` and which is better for which use case. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) explain it to some extent.

Comment: This approach is not appropriate here. Because `a` and `b` are not arguments to the function, they will not be considered by the memoization. You will always get the same result even if `a` and `b` change.

Answer (score 0):

there is a module that does this. Pypi link here: https://pypi.org/project/memoized-property/
For the above code I have this with using the module:

```
In [2]: from memoized_property import memoized_property                                                                                                       

In [3]: class test():  
   ...:         def __init__(self):  
   ...:             self.a = 0  
   ...:             self.b = 0  
   ...:        @memoized_property  
   ...:        def sum(self):  
   ...:           print('calculating...')  
   ...:           return self.a + self.b  

In [4]: t=test()                                                                                                                                              

calculating...
In [5]: t.sum                                                                                                                                                 
Out[5]: 0

In [7]: t.a=5                                                                                                                                                 

In [8]: t.sum                                                                                                                                                 
Out[8]: 0
```

Comment: This doesn't consider the values of `a` and `b` since they are not arguments to the function. You'll only get the same result. In fact, *your example shows this.* The question wants the property to update when you update the attributes of the instance.

Comment: @kindall i think my answer then does not address the op, delete?