# How to know if an instance is being initialised

Tags: python

please consider the example below:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Container(ABC):
    
    _fruits = []
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._initialised = False
    
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if name in self._fruits and hasattr(self, 'compute_total') and self._initialised:
            self.compute_total()
    
    @abstractmethod
    def compute_total(self):
        pass


class Basket(Container):
    
    _fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

    def __init__(self, apple, orange, color):
        super(Basket, self).__init__()
        self.apple = apple
        self.orange = orange
        self.color = color
        self._total = 0
        self.compute_total()
        self._initialised = True

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self._total

    def compute_total(self):
        self._total = self.apple + self.orange
```

The business requirement is to have a `total` property kept uptodate whenever one of its components, given by `_fruits`, changes.

Of course, it would be possible to compute the sum in the `total` property directly. But in the real world, this calculation is computationaly expensive, the `total` property is read often and its components don't change much. So for performance reasons I need to control when the sum is computed.

My question comes from the fact that during `Basket` initialisation, I set the `apple` property first, triggering `Container.__setattr__` But `orange` is not defined yet, so I cannot trigger `compute_total`, or I get an AttributeError. This is why I introduced the `_initialised` attribute, which will allow to trigger `compute_total` only if Basket has finished its initalisation.

Hence my question: is it possible for me to know if a `Basket` instance has finished initialising in a more elegant / pythonic way than managing a flag?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `hasattr(self, 'compute_total')` seems unnecessary for this specific example. Does the actual usecase depend on such an optional method, or this is just an overlook?

Comment: Can you simply memoize the `total` property? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176806/how-to-memoize-a-property-in-python) (or the method that calculates it)

Comment: Why not just make `compute_total` return a value instead of caring all that initialisation stuff ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 You're absolutely correct. Actually, my current implementation looks a lot like the accepted solution in your link. But I find it wordy, and it needs to be implemented in each sub-class, because the name of arguments composing total will change from a subclass to another. So in my case it's error prone when the number of subclasses starts to grow. It's actually happening, so I started looking for something more "centralised".

Comment: I recommend a [cached_property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) that computes the total. You can clear it when any fruit is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wombatz recommendation does the trick, as shown below, in an even more compact way. I was not aware of `cached_property`, it's a very interesting tool indeed. Thank you all!

```
from abc import ABC
from functools import cached_property


class Container(ABC):
    
    _fruits = []
    
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if name in self._fruits:
            try:
                del self.__dict__['total']
            except KeyError:
                pass


class Basket(Container):
    
    _fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

    def __init__(self, apple, orange, color):
        super(Basket, self).__init__()
        self.apple = apple
        self.orange = orange
        self.color = color

    @cached_property
    def total(self):
        out = self.apple + self.orange
        return out
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with a default value of 0:

```py
class Container(ABC):

  _fruits = []

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    super().__setattr__(name, value)

    if name in self._fruits:
      print(f'.{name} is changing. Recomputing total.')
      self.compute_total()

  def compute_total(self):  # This can be merged into __setattr__.
    self._total = sum(getattr(self, fruit, 0) for fruit in self._fruits)


class Basket(Container):

  _fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

  def __init__(self, apple, orange, color):
    self.apple = apple
    self.orange = orange
    self.color = color

  @property
  def total(self):
    return self._total
```

```py
basket = Basket(apple = 4, orange = 6, color = 'red')
# .apple is changing. Recomputing total.
# .orange is changing. Recomputing total.

print(basket.total)  # 10


basket.apple = 5  # .apple is changing. Recomputing total.
print(basket.total)  # 11

basket.orange = 1  # .orange is changing. Recomputing total.
print(basket.total)  # 6

basket.color = 'yellow'
print(basket.total)  # 6
```