# how to update django cached_property

Tags: python, django

I would like to use @cached_property on model property to avoid too much db access.

```
class AttrGroup(models.Model):
    ...

    @cached_property
    def options(self):
        options = AttributeOption.objects.filter(group_id=self.id)
        return options
    ...
```

This works fine.

i want to use the following function to update the value of options.But how should i do it?   for property decorator, there is setter for it.

```
def _set_options(self, value):
    for option in value:
        AttributeOption.objects.create(group_id=self.id, option=option.get('option'))
```

Comment: i have just found another decorator `lru_cache`, another solution for my problem

Answer (score 17):

You can invalidate the `cached_property` by deleting it:

```
del self.options
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional).

Comment: Better to `del self.__dict__['options']` - it makes things clearer.

Comment: you misunderstood my question, but thanks anyway. bruno's answer is what i need

Comment: Remember to check with `hasattr` or `try...except` because it may raise an exception.

Answer (score 7):

Django's `cached_property` object replaces itself with the result of the decorated function call on the first call, so you cannot invalidate the cache.

EDIT : Stupid me - of course you can, you just have to `del self.__dict__['options']` as answered by Albar - since the result is stored on the instance, removing it will make the class level `cached_property` attribute available again.

If you want something more 'reusable' you can have a look here : [Storing calculated values in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228551/storing-calculated-values-in-an-object/41230310#41230310)

Comment: thanks, actually your previous answer kind of solve my problem. As you can see, the `options` property in class `AttrGroup` is actually got from table `AttributeOption`. my ultimate purpose is to access db as few as possible when getting `options`(so i am using `cached_property` instead of `property` decorator  and i can also modify `AttributeOption` by attrgroup.options = options (this is where i need the `_set_options` method), but `cached_property` doesn't support setter. this is the place that confuse me